# What alternatives to Hans Boehm GC are out there for small devices?

Tags: c, garbage-collection, neko

I'd like to use a virtual machine like NekoVM into a small device but to build it, it requires Boehm GC, however there is no port of that GC to that small device so I was wondering if there is any alternative to it, something that could be done exclusively with C code?

Comment: My advice is to write an accurate GC for Neko if one does not already exist. I wouldn't touch Boehm's GC with a barge pole...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say your best option would be to port the GC to your platform, for which there are instructions ([libgc porting instructions](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/porting.html)).

Additionally, it should be possible to swap out the GC implementation ([NekoVM FAQ](http://nekovm.org/faq)), see vm/alloc.c file.

**EDIT**:

Hopefully useful additional links: (untested)

- [Smieciuch Garbage Collector](http://smieciuch.sourceforge.net/)
- [libgcroots](http://freshmeat.net/projects/libgcroots/) (based on libgc 7, abstracts architecture dependant bits)
- [Squirrel programming language](http://squirrel-lang.org/)

Comment: @downvoter: Is there anything wrong with this answer? A comment would help improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you'd be better off with [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), which has a very small but powerful virtual machine, has its own garbage collector built in, and runs on any platform that supports ANSI Standard C.  With just a little effort you can even build Lua on a machine that lacks standard input and standard output.  I have seen Lua running on an embedded device that was a [small LCD touch screen with an embedded CPU stuck on the back](http://www.ezlcd.com/).  Neko is good work, but I think you'll find Lua every bit as satisfying.

Comment: I am aware that Lua has its own garbage collector, but if you look into NekoVM they use libgc and do not a GC like Lua because it is not as good as libgc. I'm looking for a general purpose GC like libgc that i could replace on nekoVM

Comment: Hans has literally spent more than 20 years improving libgc.  It is not realistic to expect to find a drop-in replacement for a high-performance collector.  It is also not sensible to expect high-performance GC on a small device.  Your question asked for 'a VM like NekoVM'.  Lua qualifies.

Comment: Hans may have spent more than 20 years improving libgc but its performance is awful compared to most accurate garbage collectors.

Comment: If you do the wrong design for 20 years it's not helping at all. libgc works well for small data amounts. And it got worse in 2013.

Answer (score 3):

I could suggest TinyGC (tinygc.sf.net) - an independent lightweight implementation of the BoehmGC targeting small devices. It is fully API-compatible (even more, binary compatible) with BoehmGC v7+ but only a small subset of the API is implemented (but sufficient for Java/GCJ-like memory management) and there is no automatic threads and static data roots registration. The latter, however, may require some efforts to make NekoVM work with it (i.e., call GC_register_my_thread() and GC_add_roots()).